# Need help getting list of queries from Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I currently have three models:

```
class Match < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :rosters, dependent: :destroy
    has_and_belongs_to_many :players
end

class Player < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :matches
end

class Roster < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :match
end
```

Let's say I have a specific player's id, say `my_player_id`. My current database contains several matches, each match has 2 rosters, and each roster has 3 players.

**How can I get a list of rosters that belong to matches that belong to a player?** (the rosters that have `my_player_id` and the roster that `my_player_id` is playing against)

I've tried looking into using `joins` and `where` methods but not sure where to go from there. Any answer and explanation of the code would be appreciated!

Comment: Do u have match id  and player id ?

Comment: I have the player id but I don't want to specify any specific match, just matches in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work

```
Roster.joins(match: :players).where('players.id = ?', my_player_id)
```

**Update**

If you do `.to_sql` you will get the equivalent sql query and what it simply does is use your `associations` to `inner join` `match` with `rosters` first using the `foreign_key` and then join `players` to `matches` and your data is ready. Now you just provide the `where` clause to fetch data belonging to particular `player_id`.

Amazingly, following should also work..

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :matches
  has_many :rosters, through: :matches
end
```

and now it is as easy as

```
Player.find_by_id(player_id).rosters
```

Comment: the magic lies with the association you create, check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

The above should work fine and efficient,
another solution is to break it down to into two queries

```
match_ids = @player.matct_ids 
rosters = Roster.where(match_id: match_ids)
```

- Notice! Rails provides a list of ids for child models
- Notice
  `.where(some_attribute: [ARRAY])`takes an array as input

Comment: Cool, did not know `@player.match_ids` was a thing. Thanks!